# Sql Join Table , Part Of Select Data Condition

Tags: sql, join

I have two table table A and table B.

Table A Contain Id, Number, Time , Value1

Table B Contain Id, Data, Value2

```
Example of the Record on Table A:

Id      Number     Tried      Value1
------- ---------- --------- ---------
1       123        23         5
2       124        23         6
3       1254       23         7

Example of the Record on Table B:

Id      Data       Value2
------  ---------  -------
1       123,23     6
2       122,21     5
3       1254,23    7
```

My Purpose to Add Value 1 and Value 2 together by join condition of the table B Data with table A Number and Tried to match the record.

```
Example :
Id      (Value1 + Value2)
------- -----------------
1       11
3       14
```

My Query:

```
select a.Id , a.Value1+ b.Value2
from a
join b on substring(b.Data,1,3) = a.Number and substring(b.Data,5,2) = a.Tried
```

I had tried substring but the value of Data Record Length is different compare on Id 1 and 3 and current of Query Result only show Id 1. Is there other way to join with 1 column field that split into 2 kind of value which take out **','** to join 2 field on table a?

Comment: Using such concatenated strings as foreign key is terrible idea. Do you absolutely have to join on that?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this query would help, in Oracle

```
select a.Id , (a.Value1+ b.Value2)
from a, b
where a.id = b.id and b.Data = (a.Number || ',' || a.Tried);
```

EDIT: Based on *@Joachim Isaksson* suggestion:

```
select a.Id ,b.Id (a.Value1+ b.Value2)
from a, b
where b.Data = (a.Number || ',' || a.Tried);
```

Comment: I'm not sure a.id=b.id should be a criteria.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Modified answer based on your input. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query.

```
select A.Id, (A.Value1 + B.Value2) [Value1 + Value2] from tblA A
    inner join tblB B on A.Number = SUBSTRING(B.Data, 1, charindex(',', B.Data, 1) - 1)
        And A.Tried = SUBSTRING(B.Data, charindex(',', B.Data, 1) + 1, Len(A.Tried))
```

This I have tried in SQL Server.

Query of Nishanthi Grashia can also be converted in SQL Server. You just need to replace **||** with **+**